# Find the equation of the chord of the ellipsoid that passes through $M(2,1,-1)$ and is divided equally with this point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Given an ellipsoid with the formula: $$\mathcal{I}: \ \ \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}+\frac{z^2}{9}=1$$
>   Find the equation of the chord that passes through $M(2,1,-1)$ and is divided equally with this point (i.e $M$ lies on the center of the segment of the line inside the ellipsoid)

As we know one point on the line we have $$\frac{x-2}{l}=\frac{y-1}{m}=\frac{z+1}{n}$$ where $(l,m,n)$ is the direction vector. As $M$ is right on the center we have two points $A(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $B(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ such that $\frac{A+B}{2}=M$ and $A,B \in \mathcal{I}$. Then $(l,m,n)=(b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2,b_3-a_3)$.

From $A,B \in \mathcal{I}$, we may obtain that $$\frac{4}{25}l+8m-\frac{2}{9}n=0$$ However still I can't complete the task, I can't see where the right track is... Any help is aprreciated.

Comment: You have 3 equations and 3 unknown. Solve the system.

Comment: The intersections are calculated and than the distance.

Comment: The result seems to be a closed line on the ellipsoid.

Comment: @Moti you mean system of $A\in \mathcal{I}, B \in \mathcal{I}, AM=MB$?

Comment: Yes, as starter. You get x, y, and z in terms of l, m, n

Comment: @moti I don't think they are enough to find the variables

Comment: I think that there more than one chord.

Comment: @Moti Yeah it is possible

Comment: @Moti What do you think can I just choose any such triplet for $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ as the question does ask for just a chord?

Comment: What do you mean by triplet? You will get (x, y, z) in terms of (l, m, and.

Comment: @Moti By triplet, I mean 3 coordinates of the point $A$

Comment: OK. You will get coordinate that will by function of (l, m, n)

Comment: Shouldn’t the middle term in your last equation be $\frac m8$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from what is likely a typo in your last equation, you’re on the right track. That last equation should be $$\frac4{25}l+\frac18m-\frac29n=0.$$

So far, you’ve determined that the chord must lie on the plane $\frac4{25}x+\frac18y-\frac29z={1201\over1800}$. From here, we can see that there isn’t a unique solution to the problem. The intersection of this plane turns out to be an ellipse centered at $M$, so *every* chord through $M$ that lies on this plane satisfies the conditions of the problem.

Comment: Should the constant term be $\frac{1701}{1800}$ in the equation of the plane? If yes, then I got you. Thanks.

Comment: If we conclude all, then the intersection of the ellipsoid and this plane is a circle with the center at the point $M$?

Comment: @VIVID The right-hand side of the plane’s equation is $(4/25,1/8,-2/9)\cdot(2,1,-1)=1201/1800$. You can conclude that $M$ lies at the center of some conic on the plane, and moreover that it’s an ellipse, but it’s not a circle. Just compute the distances to the ellipsoid in a few different directions along the plane to see that they’re not all equal.